# Transfer data from SP List to MS Word using Flow

Tags: sharepoint, office365, workflow, power-automate, office365-apps

I have a SharePoint List. I want to make it so that when an Item is added to the List, it creates a MS Word document in a Document Library - and the fields of the SP List are inside my MS Word document (as a template).

I have been using this tutorial - I have followed the instructions to the letter in a test SharePoint site:

[See Tutorial Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generate-ms-word-document-consuming-sharepoint-list-data-from-a-document-templat/)

I have followed the above tutorial to the letter. Everything (almost) works:

1) I add an item to the Sharepoint List called "Offer Letter Data"

2) The flow runs successfully, and creates a MS Word document in the Document Library called "OfferLetters", by using the template in the Document Library "OfferLetterTemplate"

The only problem is, when I open the MS Word document that is created, it doesn't show the data - it shows the Quick Parts Metadata tag. The flow is collecting the information correctly - because you can see this in the flow details.

I'm missing something - I just don't know - any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated!

[Screenshot of Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8pDa.jpg)

[Screenshots of Flow being Run successfully, and data input/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCtwk.jpg)

[Screenshots of Lists, and .docx file created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvWa0.jpg)

[Screenshot of .docx file open (you can see error here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIYmg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After the first Trigger - "When Item is created", add the 2 Actions - "Populate a MS Word Template", "Create File" as shown in image below. The word document will update with the column values from the list in first Trigger.

[image: Sample Microsoft Flow]